# "uninitialized constant MongoMapper::Base" error when doing rake mongo:mongrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rubygems, mongomapper

I got the following error during my "rake mongo:mongrate" attempt:

```
$ rake mongo:mongrate --trace
(in /home/mei/Jobfully)
** Invoke mongo:mongrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment

** Execute mongo:mongrate
==  AddPricingPlans: migrating ================================================
-- add_column(:users, :plan_id, :string)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant MongoMapper::Base
/home/mei/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
```

I have the following in my Gemfile -

```
gem 'rake', '~>0.8'
gem 'mongo',        '= 1.0.7'  # must be same version as bson/bson_ext
gem 'bson',         '= 1.0.4'  # must be same version as bson_ext/mongo
gem 'bson_ext',     '= 1.0.4'  # must be same version as bson/mongo
gem 'mongo_mapper', '~> 0.8.2'
```

I also added the following line in Rakefile -

```
import 'vendor/plugins/mongrations/lib/tasks/mongo.rake'
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MongoMapper::Base` was deprecated sometime in the last year (it no longer even exists!). You now want `MongoMapper.connection` in `lib/mongo_mapper/mongrations.rb`, `def connection` rather than `MongoMapper::Base.connection`.

I'm not sure when it broke, but making that change has fixed mongrations for me.

If you want to monkeypatch it, you could use:

```
module MongoMapper
  class Base
    def self.connection
      MongoMapper.connection
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I see what you're saying.  I also noticed that there is "MongoMapper::Base.table_name_prefix" and "MongoMapper::Base.table_name_suffix}" in "def proper_table_name" in the "vendor/plugins/mongrations/lib/mongo_mapper/migrator.rb" file.

How can I fix these references to MongoMapper::Base?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you'll wait a few minutes, I'm fixing them up and releasing it as a gem with tests. You should be able to just install the gem and off you go.

Comment: @mei: `gem install mongrations`, then include it either via config.gem or in your Gemfile. See https://github.com/cheald/mongrations for the full readme.

Comment: Hi Chris, I downloaded from github.com/cheald/mongrations and did
    gem install mongrations
and also added to my Gemfile
    gem 'mongrations'

Now I'm getting 

$ rake mongo::mongrate --trace
(in /home/mei/Jobfully)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'mongo::mongrate'

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't seem to find

'vendor/plugins/mongrations/lib/tasks/mongo.rake'

Comment: See the readme - you need to add `require 'mongrations/tasks'` to your Rakefile. It shouldn't be installed as a plugin anymore.

Comment: Oops. My bad.  Thanks for pointing that out.

I now ran into a different problem... It didn't like "change_table" in "change_table :users do |t| ...".  It didn't like "add_column(:users, :plan_id, :string)" either.   

Sorry to have so many problems... I'm new at this.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Specifically, here is what I got -
[...]
** Execute mongo:mongrate
==  AddPrincingPlans: migrating ===============================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
undefined method `change_table' for #<Mongo::Connection:0xa6a6e90>

Comment: Schema migrations don't apply to MongoDB, since you can adjust the schema on the fly in your models; `add_column` makes no sense in this context. If you want to rename a collection, use `MongoMapper.connection.rename_collection(from, to)`.